# Mirrored value doesn't match the desired value while running default sequence uvm_reg_hw_reset_seq in ral test

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am new to RAL and I am running the default uvm_reg_hw_reset_seq in my test. The test is failing for a register with non zero reset value. It is passing for others which have 0 as the reset value. I get an error as follows :
"m_ral_model.xxxx_REG" value read from DUT (0x0000000000000035) does not match mirrored value (0x00000000xxxx0000).

The mirrored value shows 0 instead of 'h35

I can see the read transaction on the bus, i.e. 'h35 being read on the bus but somehow I get the above error. Also in the generated ral model I can see the configured value for this register is correct ('h35)

I am also running uvm_reg_bit_bash_seq and uvm_reg_access_seq sequence which are passing and I can see the transactions on the bus.
What could be the possible reasons for this kind of mismatch only in case of reset seq ?

I tried applying reset to the model in reset phase of my test but it did not work

```
` task reset_phase(uvm_phase phase);
     xxx_env.m_ral_env.m_ral_model.reset();
  endtask : reset_phase
`
```

Comment: Its a 32 bit register.  bit [31:16] is reserved and is configured as follos : 
RESERVED_16_31.configure(this, 16, 16, "RO", 1, 16'h0000, 1, 0, 1);                           
Bits [15:0] is configured as follows for which I am getting the error:
Reg_field_xxxx.configure(this, 16, 0, "RW", 0, 16'h0035, 1, 1, 1);